# Official Google Maps Draw Route

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I have question with [`google_maps_flutter`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter) library.  Is there any function that would allow me to draw a route between 2 markers?  I tried to search and dig into the library seems like no option (as for now). Can someone help me out or give me some article or tutorial *(must be official google maps flutter plugin)* to work from?

Thanks and happy coding.

Comment: I thought still **google_maps_flutter** is under development and there is no any method to draw route between two point.

Comment: I see, thanks @Govaadiyo for the answer! appreaciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking same as you want and also I have been googling for 2 days but didn't find any resources to draw route on flutter's official google map. Because of it's still under development, I asked to Flutter engineers. Look at below Tweet.

https://twitter.com/AmitJarsaniya07/status/1076166651815419905

[image]

If got any update, I'll update the answer.

**UPDATED :**

Thanks **@primo** for comment, Now you can draw route as per update.
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter#056

Comment: thanks @iPatel, can for the update... also can I follow you on linkedIn if that's possible? thanks :)

Comment: They have added support for polylines now which will be helpful to draw route between positions
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter#-changelog-tab-